# Python Matplotlib: Splitting one Large Graph into several Sub-Graphs (Subplot)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, subplot

Simply put suppose I have 2 lists:

A -> Has the list of names  ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H']

B -> Has the list of values [5,7,3,8,2,9,1,3]

A will be the names of the X-Axis labels and the corresponding values in B will be the height of the graph ( i.e. the Y-Axis ).

```
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import rcParams
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from operator import itemgetter

rcParams.update({'figure.autolayout': True})
plt.figure(figsize=(14,9), dpi=600)

reso_names = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H']
reso_values = [5,7,3,8,2,9,1,3]
plt.bar(range(len(reso_values)), reso_values, align='center')
plt.xticks(range(len(reso_names)), list(reso_names), rotation='vertical')

plt.margins(0.075)
plt.xlabel('X-Axis')
plt.ylabel('Y-Axis')
plt.title('Graph', {'family' : 'Arial Black',
        'weight' : 'bold',
        'size'   : 22})
plt.show()
```

This code gives the following output :[image]

However I want it such that it makes subgraphs for every 2 values. In this case there should be 4 subgraphs:

- 1st Graph has 'A' and 'B'
- 2nd Graph has 'C' and 'D'
- 3rd Graph has 'E' and 'F'
- 4th Graph has 'G' and 'H'

This splitting should be done dynamically (not 4 different loops, it should break the graph into units of 2 each depending on the size of the input, if list A has 10 values then it should give 5 subgraphs).

I figured out how to split the graph into two with half each but I need to achieve it using steps of N per graph (N in this example being 2).

The code I have for breaking the graph into 2 equal subgraphs is :

```
%matplotlib inline
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import rcParams
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from operator import itemgetter

rcParams.update({'figure.autolayout': True})
plt.figure(figsize=(14,9), dpi=600)

reso_names = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H']
reso_values = [5,7,3,8,2,9,1,3]

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=2, sharey=True, figsize=(14,18), dpi=50)
size = int(len(reso_values))
half = int( size/2 )

fig.suptitle('Graph', 
          **{'family': 'Arial Black', 'size': 22, 'weight': 'bold'})

for ax, start, end in zip(axs, (0, half), (half, size)):
    names, values = list(reso_names[start:end]), reso_values[start:end]
    ax.bar(range(len(values)), values, align='center')
    ax.set_xlabel('X-Axis')
    ax.set_ylabel('Y-Axis')
    ax.set_xticks(range(len(names)))
    ax.set_xticklabels(names, rotation='vertical')
    ax.set_xlim(0, len(names))
fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.05, top=0.95)
plt.show()
```

Which gives me : [image]

I just want the program to dynamically split the graphs into subgraphs based on the splitting number N.

Comment: It's difficult to get a sense of what you have and what want from your description and a code that relies on externes data. Can you post a representation of what it looks like now and what the result would look like ?

Comment: Basically I have 150 values, so I wanted to make it such that there are subgraphs each showing 30 at a time. Graph one has 0-29, the next one has 30-59 and so on. As opposed to all 150 values being crammed into one unreadable graph.

Comment: Largely rephrased and made the question much simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly split your lists `values`/`names` with `size` elements into `size//N + 1` list of `N` elements with this code :

```
N=3
sublists_names = [reso_names[x:x+N] for x in range(0, len(reso_names), N)]
sublists_values = [reso_values[x:x+N] for x in range(0, len(reso_values), N)]
```

Note that the last sublist will have less elements if N does not divide size.

Then you just perform a zip and plot each sublist in a different graph :

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import rcParams
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from operator import itemgetter

rcParams.update({'figure.autolayout': True})
plt.figure(figsize=(14,9), dpi=600)

reso_names = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H']
reso_values = [5,7,3,8,2,9,1,3]

N=3
sublists_names = [reso_names[x:x+N] for x in range(0, len(reso_names), N)]
sublists_values = [reso_values[x:x+N] for x in range(0, len(reso_values), N)]

size = int(len(reso_values))
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=size//N+1, sharey=True, figsize=(14,18), dpi=50)

fig.suptitle('Graph', 
          **{'family': 'Arial Black', 'size': 22, 'weight': 'bold'})

for ax, names, values in zip(axs, sublists_names, sublists_values):
    ax.bar(range(len(values)), values, align='center')
    ax.set_xlabel('X-Axis')
    ax.set_ylabel('Y-Axis')
    ax.set_xticks(range(len(names)))
    ax.set_xticklabels(names, rotation='vertical')
    ax.set_xlim(0, len(names))
    #ax.set_xlim(0, N)

fig.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.05, top=0.95)
plt.show()
```

[image]

If the list are not dividible by N, you can uncomment the last commented line so the bars stay alined on the last subplot : (`ax.set_xlim(0, N)`) :

[image]

Comment: I tried to tailor this script for my problem  but I have some problem. I want line plot not bar plot and how can I achieve this? #Yann can you give me suggestion?